# How to extend IOU situation to modify states of both users

Tags: corda

First apologize that I am still a learner on Corda. Had read the Hello World example about IOU situation. Per my understanding, the current sample only covers the IOU transaction, but does not include the change of amount of both lender and borrower have after IOU. If I want to make this, how can I modify the contract and flow parts?

Before IOU

State of UserA: 100 unit

State of UserB: 0 unit

After IOU of 10 unit

State of UserA: 90 unit

State of UserB: 10 unit

As far as I know that there must be two input states and two output states on contract shape constraints. But how can I create two new states on flow part, as most examples only have one output state?

Thanks a lot for your help and appreciate more if you can give me some hints in java but not in kotlin format.

Answer (score 0):

**Retrieving the two input states**

Suppose you are running the flow on `UserA`. You can retrieve the input state for `UserA` by querying the vault. For example:

```
val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
    null, listOf(linearId), UNCONSUMED, null)

val inputStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<IOUState>(queryCriteria).states.singleOrNull()
    ?: throw FlowException("IOU with ID $linearId not found.")
```

Retrieving the input state for `UserB` is more complex, since it is stored in `UserB`'s vault, which `UserA` can't query directly. You need to write a responder flow where `UserB` retrieves the state from their vault, then sends it across to the initiator who is building the transaction. For example:

```
@InitiatingFlow
class Initiator(val counterparty: Party, val linearId: UniqueIdentifier) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val flowSession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        flowSession.send(linearId)
        val inputStateAndRef = flowSession.receive<StateAndRef<IOUState>>().unwrap { it }
    }
}

@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
class Acceptor(val flowSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val linearId = flowSession.receive<UniqueIdentifier>().unwrap { it }

        val queryCriteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
                null, listOf(linearId), Vault.StateStatus.UNCONSUMED, null)

        val inputStateAndRef = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy<IOUState>(queryCriteria).states.singleOrNull()
                ?: throw FlowException("IOU with ID $linearId not found.")

        flowSession.send(inputStateAndRef)
    }
}
```

**Adding two output states**

You can add two output states to a transaction by simply calling `TransactionBuilder.addOutputState` twice:

```
transactionBuilder.addOutputState(new TemplateState(), TemplateContract.ID);
transactionBuilder.addOutputState(new TemplateState(), TemplateContract.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you Joel. I followed your answer and updated the flow part. However, I could not retrieve the input state of reciever(UserB) using vaultQuery, I could only retrive the input state of sender(UserA). Wanna know if the sender initiates the flow, can the detail of other states be obtained in the flow part?

Comment: Updated the answer above :)

Comment: Thank you Joel. can you show me how to unwrap stateandref in the initiator flow using java language?

Comment: For example: `receive(Object.class).unwrap(data -> { return data; });`